# How to prevent table-cell from expanding

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/pepgw4cz/1/

This is a typical article list scenario, every item has its image, title, introtext and created time. As you can see in the 2nd item, where the title is longer, the table exceeds its designated width. This could be easily solved by `flex`, but my client is using a 2011 laptop with IE9 and she wouldn't let go.

So I am stuck with table. The container's width is unknown(fit mobile screen) as well as the itemBody's width(actually, setting them to a fixed width doesn't change anything.), and the item Title has to be limited to one line(`white-space:nowrap`), which contributes to the problem.

Here is the codes, I copy it from my site so the structure looks a little wierd, but look at the fiddle and you will get the idea

```
<ul>
  <li class="card " k2id="84">
    <div class="moduleItemImageContainer">
      <a class="moduleItemImage">

      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="moduleItemBody">
      <div class="moduleItemBodyContainer">
        <span class="moduleItemDateCreated">2016-06-11</span>
        <a class="moduleItemTitle">Norm</a>
        <div class="moduleItemIntrotext">
          人民大会堂国庆宴会的细节 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="card " k2id="83">
    <div class="moduleItemImageContainer">
      <a class="moduleItemImage">

      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="moduleItemBody">
      <div class="moduleItemBodyContainer">
        <span class="moduleItemDateCreated">2016-06-11</span>

        <a class="moduleItemTitle">Looooooooong Title Long titleLooooooooong Title Long titl</a>
      <div class="moduleItemIntrotext">
          人民大会堂国庆宴会的细节 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<style>
li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

li>* {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top
}

div.moduleItemImageContainer{width:1%}

a.moduleItemImage {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x100');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

a.moduleItemTitle{white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;display:block}

div.moduleItemBody {
  padding: 16px;
}

div.moduleItemBodyContainer{
    height:68px;overflow:hidden
}

span {
  float: right
}

ul {
  width: 500px
}

</style>
```

So, how to prevent table from behaving like this?

Comment: In my opinion, the best you could do is something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pepgw4cz/8/) or use ellipsis on the title. You can probably add a `title` to the `a` and set its value to be the same as the content so that when users hover over the link they will get to see the text. If this works for you then I shall post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give your `div.moduleItemBody` a `max-width:1px;` **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pepgw4cz/10/)**

and if you want your title to break in multiple lines if it is too long then remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `a.moduleItemTitle` **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g3e225g3/2/)**

Comment: thanks, I know and that's why I said **if** for other people that may want the same thing, the first demo is actually for the OP

Comment: No problems. The only catch would be if OP somehow wants the text to be shown in full :D

Comment: and in one line? unless they change the font size or something via js according to the length of the characters, it'd be impossible!

Comment: I don't know. I am seeing an answer with ellipsis that was written and deleted. I don't know what conversation took place there.

Comment: yeah but ellipsis doesn't show the full text, it "ellipsis" it :D

Comment: Neither does `max-width: 1px` which is why I said I don't know if this solution would be acceptable for OP. Anyway I'd leave it to them.

Comment: bu the OP never said they want to show the full title in one line!

Comment: Point is OP hasn't mentioned one way or the other, which I is why I said the catch would be if OP wants it to be shown in full. Anyway, I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed'>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this asnwer

Comment: God bless you, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use bootstrap, please you can add a class `class="text-wrap"` on the cells.
This will automatically give the required `width` to the table cells according to the data its holding.